# Bash: How do I copy timestamps using touch and regex?

Tags: bash, regex, timestamp

Since this is more of a Bash question I think this is better suited for serverfault than superuser, even though I'm talking about media files.

I had to make a batch conversion of several media files, and all the output files have a new timestamp.

```
/somedir/
    file1.mpg     (correct timestamp)
    file1.mpg.m4v (wrong timestamp)
    file2.mpg     (correct timestamp)
    file2.mpg.m4v (wrong timestamp)
    ...
```

What I want to do is a batch copy of the timestamps so that each *.mpg.m4v gets the timestamp of the corresponding *.mpg file.

From my searching, it looks like I need to use `touch -r` and some regex with substitution to handle this.

Am I on the right track, and does anyone have any suggestions for how I need to do the regex (my regex knowledge, is bad, bad, bad) to handle this?

Comment: I point out that bash is the 36th top tag on SuperUser. There is a lot of Linux over there.

Comment: And it could very well belong there since it doesn't seem server-specific, but well it's ok here, too :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's see, how about...

```
for f in *.mpg; do
   touch -r "$f" "${f}.m4v"
done
```

No need for regexps, just to take the problem from the right side. It's much easier to circle through *.mpg and add .m4v to them than the contrary, although you could also write it the other way without regexps (just for fun):

```
for f in *.m4v; do
   touch -r "${f%\.m4v}" "$f"
done
```

If you want it done with one command, you could do that with `find` (restricting it to one level for safety):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.mpg' -exec touch -r {} {}.m4v \;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! There's useful knowledge in each of your three examples.

Comment: The `${foo%bar}` is part of Bash's (and other shells') parameter expansion capability and is not regular expressions (it's more closely related to globbing). Otherwise +1.

Comment: @Dennis: I never said I was using regexps, I actually emphasized that it was not necessary to use regexps for any of these solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that line.